# Using class methods in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an externally defined module which has a number of methods in it. I can get all the methods as a list with dir() like `print(dir[Descriptors])` and I get a list `['BalabanJ', 'BertzCT',...]`. Now I want to apply all the methods on a list of values [x1, x2, ...]. If I directly use `Descriptors.BalabanJ(x1)` it works. However, I want to do them in a loop like

```
from rdkit.Chem import Descriptors
for i in dir[Descriptors]:
    for x in [x1,x2,x3]:
        print(Descriptors.i(x))
```

, it says that Descriptors does not have method i in it. How can I implement this?

Comment: There is a type difference in `'BalabanJ'` and `.BalabanJ()`. The first one is string while the latter is a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that `getattr` is this for which you are looking

```
from rdkit.Chem import Descriptors
for i in dir(Descriptors):
    if callable(i):
        for x in [x1,x2,x3]:
            print(getattr(Descriptors ,i)(x))
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: I think full explanation is in BlueSheepToken post.
getattr function allows to get object attribute by name (string). 
It can be used on modules, objects etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend `inspect`:

```
from rdkit.Chem import Descriptors
import inspect

for i in inspect.getmembers(Descriptors, callable):
    for x in [1, 2, 3]:
        print(i[0], i[1](x))  # name of function of Descriptors module, result
```

Comment: This also will fail if signature of function needs 0 or more than 1 argument, or type of argument is invalid. So i remind about `inspect.signature` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve them with getattr

for instance

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def p(self):
        print(self.foo)

bar = Bar('hello word')
getattr(bar, 'p')()
```

Be aware that if there is no `method` `i`, it will raise a value error, but you can set a default method

```
getattr(bar, 'pr', lambda :print('no such method: pr'))()
```

You need to define your class and pass it as a parameter as I did for bar if it is a class method

```
from rdkit.Chem import Descriptors
for i in dir[Descriptors]:
    for x in [x1,x2,x3]:
        print(getattr(Descriptors, i)(x))
```

you can take a look at [getattr() official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)

Comment: More relevant here would be `getattr(bar, 'p')()`

Comment: @mad_ Why so? (I mean why not, but why this one is more relevant?) (I fixed it)

Answer (score 1):

For this the RDKit has the `MolecularDescriptorCalculator`.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.ML.Descriptors import MoleculeDescriptors
from rdkit.Chem import Descriptors

descriptors = [d[0] for d in Descriptors._descList]

smiles = ['CCN','CCNC', 'CCN(C)C']

for d in descriptors[:3]: # just the first three descriptors
    print(d)
    calc = MoleculeDescriptors.MolecularDescriptorCalculator([d])
    for s in smiles:
        c = calc.CalcDescriptors(Chem.MolFromSmiles(s))
        print(s, c[0])
```

Output:

```
MaxEStateIndex
CCN 4.847222222222222
CCNC 2.9305555555555554
CCN(C)C 2.125
MinEStateIndex
CCN 0.75
CCNC 1.0694444444444444
CCN(C)C 1.1388888888888888
MaxAbsEStateIndex
CCN 4.847222222222222
CCNC 2.9305555555555554
CCN(C)C 2.125
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I was keeping the question answer on purpose :)